# ClassNotFoundException for javax.xml.bind.JAXBException when switched to Spring Boot 3.1.1 & Java 17

Tags: spring-boot, java-17, wsdl2java

I am getting below ClassNotFoundException for javax.xml.bind.JAXBException with Spring Boot when I switched from SpringBoot2.7.6 and java 17 to SpringBoot 3.1.1 (and java 17 is same).

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
            at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.<init>(WSDLToJava.java:48)
            at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:181)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
            ... 2 more

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':accountAdjustmentService'.
    > Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

    * Try:
    > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
    > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    > Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Below is the build.gradle

```
group 'my.com.pkg'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
apply plugin: 'io.mateo.cxf-codegen'
apply plugin: "org.owasp.dependencycheck"
//apply plugin: "io.snyk.gradle.plugin.snykplugin"

archivesBaseName = "my-app-service"

// Set java version independent of host JAVA_HOME
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
    }
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    compile {
        extendsFrom implementation
    }
}

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = "3.1.1"
        springCloudVersion = "2022.0.3"
        dependencyManagementPluginVersion = "1.1.0"
        springdocVersion = "1.7.0"
        mockserverVersion = "5.15.0"
        //wsdl2java
        cxfCodegenGradleVersion = "1.2.1"
        apacheCxfVersion = "4.0.0" //"3.3.2"
        jaxb2BasicsVersion = "1.11.1"
        jaxbWsImplVersion = "4.0.0"
        jwsApiVersion = "3.0.0"
        jakartaAnnotationApiVersion = "1.3.5"

    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://my.artifactory.com/artifactory/repo"
            metadataSources {
                mavenPom()
                artifact()
                ignoreGradleMetadataRedirection()
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:$dependencyManagementPluginVersion"
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion"
        classpath 'org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:8.2.1'
        classpath "io.mateo:cxf-codegen-gradle:$cxfCodegenGradleVersion"
//        classpath "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://my.artifactory.com/artifactory/repo"
        metadataSources {
            mavenPom()
            artifact()
            ignoreGradleMetadataRedirection()
        }
    }
}


import io.mateo.cxf.codegen.wsdl2java.Wsdl2Java
import org.gradle.internal.logging.text.StyledTextOutputFactory

import static org.gradle.internal.logging.text.StyledTextOutput.Style

bootRun {
    sourceResources sourceSets.main
  //  systemProperty 'logging.config', 'src/main/resources/logback-local.xml'
}

//colored output borrowed from https://github.com/biasedbit/gradle-plugins/blob/master/colored-test-output.gradle
System.setProperty('org.gradle.color.failure', 'RED')
System.setProperty('org.gradle.color.progressstatus', 'YELLOW')
System.setProperty('org.gradle.color.success', 'GREEN')

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")

    implementation(
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:$springBootVersion",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc",

            "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:$springCloudVersion",
            "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap",
            "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config",

            "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:$springdocVersion",
            "com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8",
            "javax.validation:validation-api"

    )

//    implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1")
//    implementation("javax.activation:activation:1.1")

    //extra libs for javax,xml.bind exception
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.0'

    // enable soap calls to WebMethods services
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
        exclude group: 'com.github.java-json-tools', module: 'json-schema-core'
    }

    implementation 'org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core'

    // Runtime dependencies for the generated code
    implementation "org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:$jaxb2BasicsVersion"
    implementation "org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils:cxf-xjc-runtime:$apacheCxfVersion"
//    implementation "jakarta.jws:jakarta.jws-api:$jwsApiVersion   "
    implementation "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:$jaxbWsImplVersion"
    implementation ("com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:$jaxbWsImplVersion"){
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.woodstox', model: 'woodstox'
    }

    // ciscoo cxf codegen
    // For wsdl2java generating toString(), equals(), and hashcode() with xjc args
    cxfCodegen "org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins:cxf-xjc-ts:$apacheCxfVersion"
    cxfCodegen("org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:$jaxb2BasicsVersion") {
        exclude group: 'commons-beanutils', module: 'commons-beanutils'
    }
    // Other dependencies needed for code generation
    cxfCodegen "jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:$jaxbWsImplVersion"
    cxfCodegen "jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:$jakartaAnnotationApiVersion"

    // end ciscoo cxf codegen

    testImplementation(
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBootVersion",
            // Using older JUnit4 rather than current JUnit5
            "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine",

            "io.rest-assured:rest-assured",
//            "io.rest-assured:json-schema-validator",
            "io.rest-assured:json-path",
            "org.mock-server:mockserver-integration-testing:$mockserverVersion",
            "org.mock-server:mockserver-junit-rule:$mockserverVersion",
            "org.mock-server:mockserver-netty:$mockserverVersion"
    )
    testImplementation("org.mock-server:mockserver-integration-testing:$mockserverVersion"){
        exclude group: 'io.swagger.parser.v3', module: 'swagger-parser'
    }
    testImplementation("io.rest-assured:json-schema-validator"){
        exclude group: 'org.mozilla', module: 'rhino'
    }
    testImplementation "org.projectlombok:lombok"
    testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok"
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

task listAllDependencies(type: DependencyReportTask) {}

// ciscoo cxf codegen
tasks.register("myOfferWsdl", Wsdl2Java) {
    toolOptions {
        wsdl.set(file("$projectDir/src/main/resources/wsdl/MyOfferWsdl-v1.wsdl"))
        serviceName.set("MyOfferWsdl_v1_0")
        outputDir.set(file("$buildDir/generated"))
        markGenerated.set(true)
        bindingFiles.add(layout.projectDirectory.file("$projectDir/src/main/resources/wsdl/binding.xjb").asFile.absolutePath)
        xjcArgs.add("-Xts")
        xjcArgs.add("-Xequals")
        xjcArgs.add("-XhashCode")
    }
}
tasks.register("myAccountWsdl", Wsdl2Java) {
    toolOptions {
        wsdl.set(file("$projectDir/src/main/resources/wsdl/MyAccountWsdl-v1.wsdl"))
        serviceName.set("MyAccountWsdl_v1_0")
        outputDir.set(file("$buildDir/generated"))
        markGenerated.set(true)
//        bindingFiles.add(layout.projectDirectory.file("$projectDir/src/main/resources/wsdl/binding.xjb").asFile.absolutePath)
        xjcArgs.add("-Xts")
        xjcArgs.add("-Xequals")
        xjcArgs.add("-XhashCode")
    }
}
compileJava.dependsOn(wsdl2java)


test {
    if (project.hasProperty('excludeTests')) {
        exclude project.property('excludeTests')
    }

    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }

    def out = services.get(StyledTextOutputFactory).create('colored-test-output')
    out.style(Style.Normal)

    beforeSuite { suite ->
        if (suite.name.startsWith('Test Run') || suite.name.startsWith('Gradle Worker')) return
        out.println("\n" + suite.name)
    }
    afterTest { descriptor, result ->
        def style
        if (result.failedTestCount > 0) style = Style.Failure
        else if (result.skippedTestCount > 0) style = Style.ProgressStatus
        else style = Style.Success

        out.text('  ').withStyle(style).println(descriptor.name)
    }
}

task jarWithSources(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
  //  classifier = 'source'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
    from sourceSets.main.output
}

task cloneLicenses(type: Exec) {
    delete 'doc'
    ignoreExitValue false
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    errorOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    commandLine 'git', 'clone', 'https://my.gitlab.com/contracts/licenses.git', 'doc'
}

task startDockerDB(type: Exec) {
    workingDir 'database/docker-oracle'
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    if (org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) {
        commandLine = ['cmd', '/C', 'start', 'run_docker.bat']
    } else {
        commandLine './run_docker.sh'
    }
}

task shutDownDockerDB(type: Exec) {
    workingDir 'database/docker-oracle'
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    if (org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) {
        commandLine = ['cmd', '/C', 'start', 'stop_docker.bat']
    } else {
        commandLine './stop_docker.sh'
    }
}

jar {
    enabled = false
}

defaultTasks 'clean', 'wsdl2java', 'startDockerDB', 'build', 'shutDownDockerDB'
```

I tried to look for other suggestions like below but none worked.

1. Tried to explicitly as below

   ```
   implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1")
   implementation("javax.activation:activation:1.1")
   ```
2. Added the jakarta dependencies for

   ```
   implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0'
   implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.0'
   ```

   I am expecting the code to build successfully as it was building with SpringBppt2.7.6 (and openjdk17.0.2)

just to recap the code uses

```
SpringBoot 3.1.1
openjdk 17.0.2
gradle-wrapper: 8.0.2-all.zip
```

Comment: not 100% sure but I guess you have to update your jaxb component. it looks like you have good old JEE and not Jakarta jaxb version. take a look to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/4.0.0

Comment: You are using an outdated Apache CXF dependency you need to upgrade that as well to a version that supports JakartaEE.

Comment: @user3761403 were you able to solve this? I have the similar issue with same spring boot and java version.

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Spring-boot-starter-parent - 3.1.6
JDK version - 17.0.8

pom.xml

At the time of error no reference to JAXB in pom.xml

Added below dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

Exception changed to:

    Javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath

Added below dependencies to fix the issue.

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.6</version>
</dependency>

The version 2.3.6 is critical for the fix at the time of writing.
```